# JS - String with Multiple Lines

Tags: javascript, string

Say I want to achieve this:

```
var template = 
"<div>" + 
  "<div class='foo'>" + 
    "How are you?" + 
  "</div>" + 
"</div>";
```

However, I don't want to keep adding all the quotes and plusses. This gets very boilerplate very fast. I tried this:

```
var template = 
"<div>
  <div class='foo'>
    How are you? 
  </div>
</div>";
```

And it didn't fly. I would hope the JS interpreter would ignore the whitespace, but it doesn't look like its okay with it.

Is there any similar way to display a formatted string of HTML across multiple lines without having so much extra junk to type? I can't find one.

#### Update

There is one suggestion so far, which is clever. I don't know if this is any less efficient or not, and am curious if anyone else has any other ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can escape the newlines:

```
var template = 
"<div> \
  <div class='foo'> \
    How are you? \
  </div> \
</div>";
```

Comment: Clever! Never thought of that. Do you know if this would make the parsing any less efficient?